# Rstudio Version 1.2.1335 constantly crashes

Tags: ubuntu, crash, rstudio

I'm using the newest version (04/2019 of Rstudio on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit), I have two PC, one desktop and one laptop, the laptop never had this issue, however the desktop constantly crashes without any sign, it may happen when I'm not doing anything, or select something, or load a package, etc.

So, what could possibly go wrong?

PS: something for sure it crashes: right click in the terminal and select "inspect element".
Some logs when it crashes through terminal:

```
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch16: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch16: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch16: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000143
#0 0x7f6d99a4ca4f 
#1 0x7f6d99a4ce4b 
#2 0x7f6d99a4d4ce 
#3 0x7f6d94cb5890 
#4 0x7f6d6e8af1f9 
#5 0x7f6d6e8bfd5f 
#6 0x7f6d6e8c49e4 
#7 0x7f6d6e478629 
#8 0x7f6d96cfe876 QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderBatches()
#9 0x7f6d96d03ef3 QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::render()
#10 0x7f6d96cf4a23 QSGRenderer::renderScene()
#11 0x7f6d96cf4f07 QSGRenderer::renderScene()
#12 0x7f6d96d31c7e QSGDefaultRenderContext::renderNextFrame()
#13 0x7f6d96d8d1d4 QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph()
#14 0x7f6d96e48118 QQuickRenderControl::render()
#15 0x7f6d92706d50 QQuickWidgetPrivate::render()
#16 0x7f6d92706f9e QQuickWidgetPrivate::renderSceneGraph()
#17 0x7f6d951617bb QObject::event()
#18 0x7f6d960abfd3 QWidget::event()
#19 0x7f6d9270aacb QQuickWidget::event()
#20 0x7f6d9f136c88 QtWebEngineCore::RenderWidgetHostViewQtDelegateWidget::event()
#21 0x7f6d9606db3c QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper()
#22 0x7f6d96074d30 QApplication::notify()
#23 0x7f6d95134e28 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2()
#24 0x7f6d9518b6a9 QTimerInfoList::activateTimers()
#25 0x7f6d9518be81 timerSourceDispatch()
#26 0x7f6d8c4b1317 g_main_context_dispatch
#27 0x7f6d8c4b1550 
#28 0x7f6d8c4b15dc g_main_context_iteration
#29 0x7f6d9518c1ef QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents()
#30 0x7f6d9513378a QEventLoop::exec()
#31 0x7f6d9513c190 QCoreApplication::exec()
#32 0x55822dfa284f main
#33 0x7f6d9300eb97 __libc_start_main
#34 0x55822dfa5b8a _start
r8: 0000000000000014 r9: 0000000000000048 r10: 000055822e993a80 r11: 0000000000000004
r12: 000055822ec952f8 r13: 00007f6d2c10f8c0 r14: 0000000000000200 r15: 000055822e982800
di: 00007f6d2c10f8c0 si: 000055822ec952e8 bp: 000055822ec952e8 bx: 00000000000000fb
dx: 0000000000000001 ax: 0000000000000200 cx: 000055822e993b60 sp: 00007ffe377b0f70
ip: 00007f6d6e8af1f9 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000143
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after seeing many posts. The desktop I use has graphic card of Nvdia GTX 1070 and the previous driver was X.Org X server, where I think there was some compatibility issue, after updating to Nvdia driver as [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/242045/HOW-TO-GET-THE-LATEST-NVIDIA-AMD-OR-INTEL-GRAPHICS-DRIVERS-ON-UBUNTU/) described, everything solved.